# In Express.js, should I return response or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

For Express.js 4.x I can't find wether I should return the response (or next function) or not, so:

This:

```
app.get('/url', (req, res) => {
    res.send(200, { message: 'ok' });
});
```

Or this:

```
app.get('/url', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(200, { message: 'ok' });
});
```

And what is the difference?

Comment: Nothing, they're essentially identical.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't. The `(req, res)` signature tells express this is the last function in the chain, and it does not expect a return value from this function. In fact, as all routing functions are considered middleware, express *never* expects a return value, and the way you trigger the next function down the line is by literally doing that, and calling `next()`.

Of course you *can* add a return statement, but it won't "do anything", beyond the JS engine performing some additional (but meaningless) overhead.

Comment: We don't want overhead! Choice seems obvious now, thank you =)

Comment: It's 2015. We don't care about the nanoseconds of overhead for symbol reservation and resolution compared to the milliseconds of function execution =) But in terms of sensible code, no need to mark an explicit `return` if it won't be consumed by anything.

Comment: I guess what I'm after here isn't nanoseconds, to which I agree with you. Really all I'm looking for is best practices, so a choice of performance overhead (even in nanoseconds) or not, is an easy one.

Comment: nah, in this case it's a question of "what does everyone do?", entirely detached from performance. As general JavaScript practice, any function whose return will not be capture is left without explicit return (be that in express or not), so in this case it's a best practice that comes from JavaScript itself, rather than express specifically.

Comment: better to save of tonnes of debugging time following any consistent scheme. Personally not a very big fan of such rules, but using consist return has saved me a lot of times

Comment: Don't use `return` if you're not returning anything. That's the convention. There is no actual "rule" because only the JS spec contains rules, and it has no opinion, it just says that without an explicit return, functions return `undefined`.

Answer (score 44):

I do not agree with the answer above. 
Sometimes the callback function can return several responses depending on the logic of the app:

```
router.post("/url", function(req, res) {
// (logic1)
     res.send(200, { response: 'response 1' });
   // (logic2) 
      res.send(200, { message: 'response 2' });
    }})
```

This will throw this error:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client

Which can actually be solved with using **return**. It can also be solved with using if else clauses.

Comment: You are absolutely right in the way that this makes a difference logically. However, the question simply meant whether it made a difference semantically. Of course, if you do not return the first response, all subsequent responses will thrown your error. Thank you for making this addition!

Comment: @Nicky what brought me to this post was I starting using eslint with my code, which has a rule 'consistent return'.  The ESLint docs on consistent return say this, require `return` statements to either always or never specify values.  In most all of my controller functions I am not returning values but sending a response, should I simply disable this ESLint feature?

Comment: Note that "return to prevent more code from running" is not related to express, that's a universal JS behaiour. You're not "returning" data to anything, you're just exiting the function early. The original post did _not_ show any code branching, and so in _their_ example, there is no early return anywhere, and adding `return` to the code shown does nothing.

Answer (score 10):

It depends.

Calling the `res` or `req` callback doesn't mean your routing function is gonna stop working

```
app.get('/url', (req, res) => {

    if (true) {
        res.send(200, { message: 'ok' });
    }

    const newFunction = () => {
        // stuff useless to your routing function
    }
    newFunction()

});
```

In here the `newFunction()` is gonna get called and it's useless, it's gonna impact your server performances.

you better use `return res.send(200, { message: 'ok' });` everytime, except if you wanna make a process in the background...

A process typically that can't be expected more than the classical 30 seconds http request. (Me I am making one that takes 4 or 5 hours everyday for example :D)

Comment: and can I call multiple res statements in one callback? 
I want to delete and res.status(200) and also after that I want to create something else and send 201 all in one route

Comment: just one res.send possible, no more.